# Weblogic errors after getting deployed (published) : Error 503--Service Unavailable

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, weblogic11g, http-status-code-503

I have a small web application where I am using Spring, Hibernate and JSF2.0.

I am deploying my application to Weblogic 10.3.6 which in integrated with Eclipse server. When I publish application to server, it gets published(deployed) however it takes quite some time to get published when compared to Glassfish.

The problem I am having is when I try to run application from browser I am getting the following error in browser, though I do not see any errors or exception in logs. How can I resolve this issue? And why it is taking so much to gets deployed to server?

```
Error 503--Service Unavailable
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.5.4 503 Service Unavailable

The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary 
overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this 
is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. If known, 
the length of the delay may be indicated in a Retry-After header. 
If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD handle the response as it would 
for a 500 response.

    Note: The existence of the 503 status code does not imply that a server 
    must use it when becoming overloaded. Some servers may wish to simply 
    refuse the connection.
```

Comment: Did you review weblogic logs or application availability in admin page? Did you ensure your application is started?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem where I am trying to access my SpringBoot application deployed onto Weblogic through an ANGULAR UI frontend. The exception handling by Spring takes care of most of the exceptions but for situation as above where the service is down I am not able to catch it in Springboot and the Angular app shows a cluttered message from the Weblogic server. How can I catch this exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the admin console, 
Check the status of your server,
Check the status of the application itself that you were trying to deploy. Make sure its started and ready to take requests.

Regarding why its taking long to deploy, I think its down to using Eclipse itself IMO.
When redeploying app's if you deploy some of the files as libraries then the deployment will be much more fasted. If you are trying to include all the libraries in your EAR file itself then the server will take longer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have resolved the issue of getting error page as there was some settings of my laptop got changed and hence it was not communicating properly with the database. However the issue of slowness still remains only when I start the server from Eclipse console for the first time. Subsequent republishing or restarting is fine.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure your deployment is in active state.After deployment your deployed file state is prepared.To change it to active mode follow the below steps:

1. Click Deployment tab in left side console and go to summary of Deployment.
2. Now you will able to see the status of your Deployment which will be prepared now.
3. Click on control tab above.
4. Select your war file and check start option.
5. Then select for all services.

It will change state to active mode.
;)